# How to delete a row from a table in SQL Server using PowerShell script?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

```
$uncServer = "\\10.243.174.102\e$"
$uncFullPath = "$uncServer\New folder\Demo.txt"
$username = "XYZ"
$password = "xyz"

net use $uncServer $password /USER:$username


$SQLServer = "AP-PUN-SRSTEP29\MSSQLSERVER12" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances! 
$SQLDBName = "SystemDB"
$SqlQuery = "Delete * from V_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.4.4'";

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
#$SqlConnection.open()


$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
```

I have SQL Server 2012 installed on a remote server and I want to delete a row from a particular table in a specific database, from a local machine using a PowerShell script. Is is possible to do that?

Comment: SO doesnt work for you, what is you code? What have you tried?

Comment: Hey hi esperento, Actually i didn't had the code with me at that time so i could not upload it but now i have edited the question and uploaded the code as well which i tried by searching on google but it doesn't work, so could please help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is using ADO.NET objects as you would in any .NET application. The PowerShell example below doesn't require SQL tools to be installed.

To execute the query using Windows authentication, specify `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string:

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE YourTableID = 1", $connection);
$connection.Open();
$rowsDeleted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Write-Host "$rowsDeleted rows deleted";
$connection.Close();
```

To execute the query using SQL authentication, specify `User ID=YourSqlLogin;Password=YourSqlLoginPassword` in the connection string.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;User ID=YourSqlLogin;Password=YourSqlLoginPassword";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE YourTableID = 1", $connection);
$connection.Open();
$rowsDeleted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Write-Host "$rowsDeleted rows deleted";
$connection.Close();
```

In either case, `DELETE` permissions on the table are required.

I'm not sure of the purpose of the `NET USE` command in the script you added to your question, unless that is to authenticate to the server in a workgroup environment. Personally, I would just use SQL authentication and remove the `NET USE` ugliness.

**EDIT:**

In the case of multiple `SELECT` statements in the same batch, each will return a separate recordset. This will require invoking `NextRecordset` if you are using a `DataReader`, which will return false when no more recordsets are available:

```
$reader = $command.ExecuteReader();
do {
    While($reader.Read()) {
        #process row here;
    }
} while($reader.NextResult());
```

Alternatively, you could use a `DataAdapter` to fill a 'DataSet'. The `DataSet` will contain a separate `DataTable` for each resultset:

```
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command);
$ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$null = $da.Fill($ds);
foreach($dt in $ds.Tables) {
    $dt | Out-GridView;
}
```

You could also tweak your SQL query to concatenate the results into a single resultset using `UNION ALL` if the number of columns and data types are identical. Here's an example snippet:

```
$sqlQuery = @("
SELECT *
FROM DB926.dbo.Version_Solution 
WHERE Notes ='9.2.7'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM DB_926.dbo.Version_Solution
WHERE Notes ='9.2.7'";
);
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlQuery, $connection);
```

Comment: Same error occurs while using the above code as well mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Yes, Even i added the user id and password in connection string and tried it and also removed the unwanted code of NET USE which i thought would be needed because the SQLServer is installed on remote machine and after all this changes code was working perfectly, anyways thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Hi Dan Guzman, Is it possible to delete the entry from a Table present in two different databases? , like i tried giving two different database name for eg-  Initial Catalog="DB1","DB2" but it is giving me error. How should i add a code for another Database instead of repeating the same code again for deleting entry from other DB aswell.

Comment: @SRP, if you databases are on the same server, qualify the table names with the database name and execute multiple `DELETE` statements in the same batch: `DELETE FROM DB1.dbo.YourTable WHERE YourTableID = 1;DELETE FROM DB2.dbo.YourTable WHERE YourTableID = 1;`

Comment: It worked for delete statement but for Select statement it does not work, for select statement is their any another syntax? This the statement i have added in the code "Select * from DB926.dbo.Version_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.2.7';Select * from DB_926.dbo.Version_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.2.7'"

Comment: It shows data only from one database and not from both.

Comment: @SRP, multiple recordsets are returned when you execute multiple `SELECT` statements in the same batch. I added examples to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this :

```
$uncServer = "\\10.243.174.102\e$"
$uncFullPath = "$uncServer\New folder\Demo.txt"
$username = "XYZ"
$password = "xyz"

net use $uncServer $password /USER:$username


$SQLServer = "AP-PUN-SRSTEP29\MSSQLSERVER12" #use Server\Instance for named SQL instances! 
$SQLDBName = "SystemDB"
$SqlQuery = "Delete from V_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.4.4'";

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlConnection.open()


$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Hi Esperento57, the above code is giving exception at "$SqlConnection.open()"  saying Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s) "Login failed for user 'XYZ' .  I think i also need to give username and password for SqlServer as well. The above username and password is for Remote machine where SQLServer is installed. If i need to give credentials of SQLServer as well then where and how should i give it?

Comment: Hi Esperento57, Is it possible to delete the entry from a Table present in two different databases? , like i tried giving two different database name for eg-  Initial Catalog="DB1","DB2" but it is giving me error. How should i add a code for another Database instead of repeating the same code again for deleting entry from other DB aswell.

Comment: No, It is possible to delete, the above answer given by Dan Guzman in comments worked successfully it deleted the entries from tables present in two different databases and the databases were on the same server.

Comment: Its okay Sir :-), But the select statement doesn't seem to run on the same server for tables in two database.

Comment: select or delete? Do you want join 2 tables ?

Comment: @ Esperento57, No i able to delete entries from two table using this command "Delete from DB926.dbo.Version_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.2.8';Delete from DB_926.dbo.Version_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.2.8'"  but when i try this command for select statement like this "Select * from DB926.dbo.Globals WHERE Version_Number ='9.2.3.2';Select * from DB926.dbo.Version_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.2.7'"  it only displays value from one table and not from both.

Comment: If your tables hâve same structure you can si it:  "Select * from DB926.dbo.Globals WHERE Version_Number ='9.2.3.2' union all Select * from DB926.dbo.Version_Solution WHERE Notes ='9.2.7' . Otherwise you must exécute 2 querys